# how to move fields custom object to opportunity?

Tags: custom-object, standard-objects

one custom second one is opportunity. First I created a custom object like as opportunity. But I want move fields (custom object) from to standard opportunity. In opportunity also some custom fields added. Is there any way to move fields please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't move the fields(metadata) from one object to another object. You have to create the field name same as old object field name and then migrate the data to the standard oject

Comment: @prabhu migrate the data using data loader or any direct way?

Comment: 1. you can use apex script to migrate the data. or you can use data loader

Answer (score 0):

if you want to transfer data from one custom object field to any opportunity field you can use master-detail or lookup relationship.

But you can not move fields like if u have test1__c field in custom object and you want cut it from here and move it to opportunity it is not possible. Although U can create same name (test1__c) custom field in opportunity.

Comment: my actual scenario is previously i created custom object insted of opportunity. now i want use opportunity same like custom object

Comment: ok. So you can just create that custom objects fields in your opportunity. You can't move that field directly in Opportunity.